# buildbot scheduler not work

Tags: scheduler, buildbot

I expected the buildbot trigger the builder when it detected a new revision had been commited to svn, but it failed. Only when the Periodic scheduler is added can the builder be triggered, but it's not my expectation. According to the log,

```
2012-07-30 23:51:33-0400 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2012-07-30 23:51:33-0400 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 11 .. 12
2012-07-30 23:51:33-0400 [-] Adding change revision 12
2012-07-30 23:51:34-0400 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
```

new commit is detected, but builder is not triggered.

Following is my configure file:

```
c = BuildmasterConfig = {}
from buildbot.buildslave import BuildSlave
c['slaves'] = [BuildSlave("example-slave", "pass")]

c['slavePortnum'] = 9989

INTERVAL = 30

from buildbot.changes.svnpoller import SVNPoller, split_file_branches
svn_url = 'file:///data/subREPOS/project'
c['change_source'] = []
c['change_source'].append(SVNPoller(svnurl = svn_url,
                                    split_file=split_file_branches,    pollinterval=INTERVAL))

from buildbot.schedulers.basic import Scheduler
from buildbot.scheduler import Periodic

c['schedulers'] = []
c['schedulers'].append(Scheduler(name="General", branch=None,
                                 treeStableTimer=3,
                                 builderNames=["testbuilder"]))
c['schedulers'].append(Periodic("Periodic", ['testbuilder', ], INTERVAL))

from buildbot.process.factory import BuildFactory
from buildbot.steps.source import SVN
from buildbot.steps.shell import ShellCommand, Compile

factory = BuildFactory()

factory.addStep(ShellCommand(command=["ls"]))
factory.addStep(SVN(svn_url, None, 'incremental',workdir='sourcedir' ))
factory.addStep(Compile(workdir="sourcedir", command=["make"]))

from buildbot.config import BuilderConfig

c['builders'] = []
c['builders'].append(
    BuilderConfig(name="testbuilder",
      slavenames=["example-slave"],
      factory=factory))
```

Comment: if the Periodic is removed, the builer will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If the `SVNPoller` is working properly, you should see a line like

```
added change Change(revision=u'08b4489c26aafc0600bb6cda647c47dc422a6839', who=u'Jaka Kranjc <lynxlupodian@users.sourceforge.net>', branch=u'master', comments=u'fix msvc build error - no strcasecmp', when=1346362922, category=None, project=u'gemrb', repository=u'git://gemrb.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/gemrb/gemrb', codebase=u'') to database
```

My guess is that the branch listed there is different than the one specified by `Scheduler`, hence it isn't getting triggered.