# buildbot scheduler not working

Tags: scheduler, buildbot

I have essentially the same problem discussed here [buildbot scheduler not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734352/buildbot-scheduler-not-work), but the answer there may not apply -- possibly because I've got a newer version of buildbot

```
>buildbot --version
Buildbot version: 0.8.12
Twisted version: 16.2.0
```

running on Windows 7 64-bit.

I'd like an svn commit to trigger the buildbot builders, but instead, only the Periodic scheduler (when enabled) triggers the builders. The log shows

```
2016-06-10 11:40:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:40:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: svnurl=file:///G:/buildbot/buildbot_repo/trunk/triggers_for_testing, root=file:///G:/buildbot/buildbot_repo, so prefix=trunk/triggers_for_testing
2016-06-10 11:40:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: starting at change 31
2016-06-10 11:40:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes None .. 31
2016-06-10 11:40:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:40:38-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:40:38-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 32
2016-06-10 11:40:38-0700 [-] Adding change revision 32
2016-06-10 11:40:38-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
```

But the scheduler does not trigger the builders.

The answer at the above cited question says the log should include entries "added change Change(..." if the SVNPoller is working, and then advises what to look for within those entries.  My log does not include any such entries.

Below are a snip of the master.cfg and (tail of) twistd.log files.
Any help most appreciated.

snip of master.cfg:

```
# -*- python -*-
# ex: set syntax=python:

_test_buildbot            = False # Set to True to use configuration settings that facilicate testing
_poll_test_repository     = True # Set to True to enable testing of an SVNPoller and SingleBranchScheduler monitoring the local repository "file:///G:/buildbot/buildbot_repo/trunk/triggers_for_testing".
_hypersensitive_SVNPoller = True # Set to True to facilicate testing of the SVNPoller and SingleBranchScheduler, making them poll frequently and look for changes *anywhere*.


# This is a sample buildmaster config file. It must be installed as
# 'master.cfg' in your buildmaster's base directory.

# This is the dictionary that the buildmaster pays attention to. We also use
# a shorter alias to save typing.
c = BuildmasterConfig = {}

####### STEPS
<SNIPPED...>

####### BUILDSLAVES
from buildbot import buildslave
from buildbot.schedulers.basic import SingleBranchScheduler
from buildbot.changes import filter

# The 'slaves' list defines the set of recognized buildslaves. Each element is
# a BuildSlave object, specifying a unique slave name and password.  The same
# slave name and password must be configured on the slave.
c['slaves'] = [ buildslave.BuildSlave("win64-worker",   "pass"),
                buildslave.BuildSlave("centos7-worker", "pass"),
                ]

# 'protocols' contains information about protocols which master will use for
# communicating with slaves.
# You must define at least 'port' option that slaves could connect to your master
# with this protocol.
# 'port' must match the value configured into the buildslaves (with their
# --master option)
c['protocols'] = {'pb': {'port': 9989}}

####### SCHEDULERS
from buildbot.schedulers.timed import Periodic

# Configure the Schedulers, which decide how to react to incoming changes.  In this
# case, just kick off a 'ifort_win32_build', 'ifort_win64_build', gfortran_win64_build, and gfortran_centos7_build builds

# define the dynamic scheduler
trunk_sf_codechanged = SingleBranchScheduler(name = "trunk_sf_codechanged",
                                     change_filter = filter.ChangeFilter(
                                                        repository = "svn://kraken",
                                                        branch = None if _hypersensitive_SVNPoller else "trunk/sf_code",
                                                        ),
                                     treeStableTimer = 1 * 30 if _test_buildbot else 10 * 60,
                                     builderNames = ["ifort_win32_build",
                                                     "ifort_win64_build",
                                                     "gfortran_win64_build",
                                                     "gfortran_centos7_build",
                                                     ],
                                            )
triggers_for_testing_changed = SingleBranchScheduler(name = "test_triggers_changed",
                                     change_filter = filter.ChangeFilter(
                                                        repository = "file:///G:/buildbot/buildbot_repo/trunk/triggers_for_testing",
                                                        branch = None,
                                                        ),
                                     treeStableTimer = 1 * 20,
                                     builderNames = ["ifort_win32_build",
                                                     "ifort_win64_build",
                                                     "gfortran_win64_build",
                                                     "gfortran_centos7_build",
                                                     ],
                                            )

# define the periodic scheduler
periodicscheduler = Periodic(name = "Every 4 Days",
                           builderNames = ["ifort_win32_build",
                                           "ifort_win64_build",
                                           "gfortran_win64_build",
                                           "gfortran_centos7_build",
                                          ],
                           periodicBuildTimer = 10*60 if _test_buildbot else 4*24*60*60,
                           )

# define the available schedulers
c['schedulers'] = [
                    trunk_sf_codechanged,
                  ]
if _poll_test_repository:
    c['schedulers'].append(triggers_for_testing_changed)
if _test_buildbot:
    c['schedulers'].append(periodicscheduler)

####### CHANGESOURCES
from buildbot.changes.svnpoller import SVNPoller, split_file_branches
from twisted.python import log

# the 'change_source' setting tells the buildmaster how it should find out
# about source code changes.

svn_nwra_mry_poller = SVNPoller(svnurl = "svn://kraken" if _hypersensitive_SVNPoller else "svn://kraken/trunk/sf_code",
                      svnuser = "buildbot",
                      svnpasswd = "buildbot",
                      svnbin = 'C:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/svn.exe',
                      pollinterval = 1 * 20 if _test_buildbot else 10 * 60,
                      split_file = split_file_branches)

test_trigger_poller = SVNPoller(svnurl = "file:///G:/buildbot/buildbot_repo/trunk/triggers_for_testing",
                      svnuser = "buildbot",
                      svnpasswd = "buildbot",
                      svnbin = 'C:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/svn.exe',
                      pollinterval = 1 * 20,
                      split_file = split_file_branches)

c['change_source'] = [  
                        svn_nwra_mry_poller,
                     ]
if _poll_test_repository:
    c['change_source'].append(test_trigger_poller)

<SNIPPED...>
```

tail of twistd.log:

```
2016-06-10 10:39:26-0700 [-] BuildMaster is running
2016-06-10 10:39:26-0700 [-] Main loop terminated.
2016-06-10 10:39:26-0700 [-] Server Shut Down.
2016-06-10 10:39:26-0700 [-] Server Shut Down.
2016-06-10 11:33:48-0700 [-] Loading buildbot.tac...
2016-06-10 11:33:48-0700 [-] Loaded.
2016-06-10 11:33:48-0700 [-] twistd 16.2.0 (C:\Users\buildbot\AppData\Local\Programs\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\python.exe 2.7.10) starting up.
2016-06-10 11:33:48-0700 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.
2016-06-10 11:33:48-0700 [-] Starting BuildMaster -- buildbot.version: 0.8.12
2016-06-10 11:33:48-0700 [-] Loading configuration from 'G:\\buildbot\\master\\master.cfg'
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] Setting up database with URL 'sqlite:///state.sqlite'
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] setting database journal mode to 'wal'
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] Using SQLite Version (3, 6, 21)
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] NOTE: this old version of SQLite does not support WAL journal mode; a busy master may encounter 'Database is locked' errors.  Consider upgrading.
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] adding 2 new changesources, removing 0
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] adding 2 new slaves, removing 0
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] adding 4 new builders, removing 0
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] trying to load status pickle from G:\buildbot\master\ifort_win32_build\builder
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] added builder ifort_win32_build with tags None
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] trying to load status pickle from G:\buildbot\master\gfortran_win64_build\builder
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] added builder gfortran_win64_build with tags None
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] trying to load status pickle from G:\buildbot\master\gfortran_centos7_build\builder
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] added builder gfortran_centos7_build with tags None
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] trying to load status pickle from G:\buildbot\master\ifort_win64_build\builder
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] added builder ifort_win64_build with tags None
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] PBServerFactory starting on 9989
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] Starting factory <twisted.spread.pb.PBServerFactory instance at 0x00000000056AF508>
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] adding scheduler 'test_triggers_changed'
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] adding scheduler 'trunk_sf_codechanged'
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] WebStatus using (G:\buildbot\master\public_html)
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] RotateLogSite starting on 8010
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] Starting factory <buildbot.status.web.baseweb.RotateLogSite instance at 0x0000000005711208>
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] Setting up http.log rotating 10 files of 10000000 bytes each
2016-06-10 11:33:49-0700 [-] BuildMaster is running
2016-06-10 11:34:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:34:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: svnurl=file:///G:/buildbot/buildbot_repo/trunk/triggers_for_testing, root=file:///G:/buildbot/buildbot_repo, so prefix=trunk/triggers_for_testing
2016-06-10 11:34:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: starting at change 30
2016-06-10 11:34:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes None .. 30
2016-06-10 11:34:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:34:29-0700 [Broker,0,192.168.77.222] slave 'centos7-worker' attaching from IPv4Address(TCP, '192.168.77.222', 53458)
2016-06-10 11:34:29-0700 [Broker,0,192.168.77.222] Got slaveinfo from 'centos7-worker'
2016-06-10 11:34:29-0700 [Broker,0,192.168.77.222] Starting buildslave keepalive timer for 'centos7-worker'
2016-06-10 11:34:29-0700 [Broker,0,192.168.77.222] bot attached
2016-06-10 11:34:29-0700 [Broker,0,192.168.77.222] Buildslave centos7-worker attached to gfortran_centos7_build
2016-06-10 11:34:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:34:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:34:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 30 .. 30
2016-06-10 11:34:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:34:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:34:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:34:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 30 .. 30
2016-06-10 11:34:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:35:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:35:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 30 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:35:09-0700 [-] Adding change revision 31
2016-06-10 11:35:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:35:26-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] slave 'win64-worker' attaching from IPv4Address(TCP, '169.254.203.227', 53461)
2016-06-10 11:35:26-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] Got slaveinfo from 'win64-worker'
2016-06-10 11:35:26-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] Starting buildslave keepalive timer for 'win64-worker'
2016-06-10 11:35:26-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] bot attached
2016-06-10 11:35:26-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] Buildslave win64-worker attached to ifort_win32_build
2016-06-10 11:35:26-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] Buildslave win64-worker attached to gfortran_win64_build
2016-06-10 11:35:26-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] Buildslave win64-worker attached to ifort_win64_build
2016-06-10 11:35:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:35:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:35:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:35:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:35:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:35:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:35:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:35:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:36:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:36:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:36:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:36:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:36:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:36:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:36:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:36:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:36:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:36:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:36:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:36:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:37:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:37:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:37:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:37:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:37:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:37:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:37:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:37:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:37:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:37:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:37:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:37:49-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:38:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:38:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:38:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:38:09-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:38:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:38:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:38:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 31
2016-06-10 11:38:29-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [-] Received SIGINT, shutting down.
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [-] (TCP Port 8010 Closed)
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [-] Stopping factory <buildbot.status.web.baseweb.RotateLogSite instance at 0x0000000005711208>
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [Broker,0,192.168.77.222] BuildSlave.detached(centos7-worker)
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [Broker,0,192.168.77.222] releaseLocks(<BuildSlave 'centos7-worker'>): []
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [Broker,0,192.168.77.222] Buildslave centos7-worker detached from gfortran_centos7_build
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] BuildSlave.detached(win64-worker)
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] releaseLocks(<BuildSlave 'win64-worker'>): []
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] Buildslave win64-worker detached from ifort_win32_build
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] Buildslave win64-worker detached from gfortran_win64_build
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [Broker,1,169.254.203.227] Buildslave win64-worker detached from ifort_win64_build
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [-] (TCP Port 9989 Closed)
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [-] Stopping factory <twisted.spread.pb.PBServerFactory instance at 0x00000000056AF508>
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [-] Main loop terminated.
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [-] Server Shut Down.
2016-06-10 11:38:32-0700 [-] Server Shut Down.
2016-06-10 11:39:56-0700 [-] Loading buildbot.tac...
2016-06-10 11:39:57-0700 [-] Loaded.
2016-06-10 11:39:57-0700 [-] twistd 16.2.0 (C:\Users\buildbot\AppData\Local\Programs\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\python.exe 2.7.10) starting up.
2016-06-10 11:39:57-0700 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.
2016-06-10 11:39:57-0700 [-] Starting BuildMaster -- buildbot.version: 0.8.12
2016-06-10 11:39:57-0700 [-] Loading configuration from 'G:\\buildbot\\master\\master.cfg'
2016-06-10 11:39:57-0700 [-] Setting up database with URL 'sqlite:///state.sqlite'
2016-06-10 11:39:57-0700 [-] setting database journal mode to 'wal'
2016-06-10 11:39:57-0700 [-] Using SQLite Version (3, 6, 21)
2016-06-10 11:39:57-0700 [-] NOTE: this old version of SQLite does not support WAL journal mode; a busy master may encounter 'Database is locked' errors.  Consider upgrading.
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] adding 2 new changesources, removing 0
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] adding 2 new slaves, removing 0
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] adding 4 new builders, removing 0
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] trying to load status pickle from G:\buildbot\master\ifort_win32_build\builder
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] added builder ifort_win32_build with tags None
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] trying to load status pickle from G:\buildbot\master\gfortran_win64_build\builder
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] added builder gfortran_win64_build with tags None
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] trying to load status pickle from G:\buildbot\master\gfortran_centos7_build\builder
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] added builder gfortran_centos7_build with tags None
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] trying to load status pickle from G:\buildbot\master\ifort_win64_build\builder
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] added builder ifort_win64_build with tags None
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] PBServerFactory starting on 9989
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] Starting factory <twisted.spread.pb.PBServerFactory instance at 0x000000000575E8C8>
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] adding scheduler 'test_triggers_changed'
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] adding scheduler 'trunk_sf_codechanged'
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] WebStatus using (G:\buildbot\master\public_html)
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] RotateLogSite starting on 8010
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] Starting factory <buildbot.status.web.baseweb.RotateLogSite instance at 0x00000000057BB0C8>
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] Setting up http.log rotating 10 files of 10000000 bytes each
2016-06-10 11:39:58-0700 [-] BuildMaster is running
2016-06-10 11:40:03-0700 [Broker,0,169.254.203.227] slave 'win64-worker' attaching from IPv4Address(TCP, '169.254.203.227', 53479)
2016-06-10 11:40:03-0700 [Broker,0,169.254.203.227] Got slaveinfo from 'win64-worker'
2016-06-10 11:40:03-0700 [Broker,0,169.254.203.227] Starting buildslave keepalive timer for 'win64-worker'
2016-06-10 11:40:03-0700 [Broker,0,169.254.203.227] bot attached
2016-06-10 11:40:03-0700 [Broker,0,169.254.203.227] Buildslave win64-worker attached to ifort_win32_build
2016-06-10 11:40:03-0700 [Broker,0,169.254.203.227] Buildslave win64-worker attached to gfortran_win64_build
2016-06-10 11:40:03-0700 [Broker,0,169.254.203.227] Buildslave win64-worker attached to ifort_win64_build
2016-06-10 11:40:05-0700 [Broker,1,192.168.77.222] slave 'centos7-worker' attaching from IPv4Address(TCP, '192.168.77.222', 53480)
2016-06-10 11:40:05-0700 [Broker,1,192.168.77.222] Got slaveinfo from 'centos7-worker'
2016-06-10 11:40:05-0700 [Broker,1,192.168.77.222] Starting buildslave keepalive timer for 'centos7-worker'
2016-06-10 11:40:05-0700 [Broker,1,192.168.77.222] bot attached
2016-06-10 11:40:05-0700 [Broker,1,192.168.77.222] Buildslave centos7-worker attached to gfortran_centos7_build
2016-06-10 11:40:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:40:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: svnurl=file:///G:/buildbot/buildbot_repo/trunk/triggers_for_testing, root=file:///G:/buildbot/buildbot_repo, so prefix=trunk/triggers_for_testing
2016-06-10 11:40:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: starting at change 31
2016-06-10 11:40:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes None .. 31
2016-06-10 11:40:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:40:38-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:40:38-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 31 .. 32
2016-06-10 11:40:38-0700 [-] Adding change revision 32
2016-06-10 11:40:38-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:40:58-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:40:58-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:40:58-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 32 .. 32
2016-06-10 11:40:58-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:41:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
2016-06-10 11:41:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: no changes
2016-06-10 11:41:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: _process_changes 32 .. 32
2016-06-10 11:41:18-0700 [-] SVNPoller: finished polling None
2016-06-10 11:41:38-0700 [-] SVNPoller: polling
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by deleting altogether the

```
split_file = split_file_branches
```

argument to the two SVNPoller constructors.  It seems the split_file is not necessary for polling a single branch in a repository organized as mine.